# Fullsimplify output depends on variable order

Tags: bugs, simplifying-expressions

**Bug introduced in 5.2 or earlier and persisting through 12.0 or later**

---

*Mathematica 11.3.0.0* (used on a Mac) seems to give different results when using [`FullSimplify`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FullSimplify.html).

**Any suggestions about what is happening?**

**Can this be reproduced on all platforms?**

```
Quit[]

a = f g + h j;
b = a;

Assuming[c > a, FullSimplify[b < c]]
(* f g + h j < c *)

Assuming[c > a, FullSimplify[c > b]]
(* True *)
```

Comment: Reproduced also with Mathematica 5.2 and 8.0.4 on Win7x64. A very old bug.

Comment: I have reproduced this on a Mac (v. 11.3.0.0 in the original posting, plus v. 12.0.0.0)

Answer (score 3):

<sup>This answer is a *community wiki* post, feel free to edit and add further information.</sup>

---

This problems was reported to Wolfram Support on 30/07/2019.

> Support case ID [CASE:4284793].

**Wolfram Support acknowledged this behaviour as a bug.**

An issue report has been sent to Wolfram developers.

We can reproduce this on

- *WolframCloud (12.0 for Linux x86 (64-bit) )* (@rhermans)
- *[tio.run](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78/z@gKDOvxMGtNCcnODO3ICczrTI6WcFOIU1BIV1BWyFDIUtBB8iBsW0UkmP//wcA) (11.3 for Linux x86 (64-bit) )* (@rhermans)
- *Mathematica 5.2, 8.0.4, 11.3 and 12.0 for Windows 64* (@innaiz, @rhermans)
- *Mathematica 11.3. for Mac* (@Øistein OP)

#### Fails:

```
Simplify[c > f  g + h j , f g + h j < c]
FullSimplify[c > f  g + h j , f g + h j < c]
FullSimplify[c > f  g + h j , Assumptions -> f g + h j < c]
Assuming[f g + h j < c, FullSimplify[c > f  g + h j ]]
```

#### Doesn't fail

```
Simplify[c > f  g + h , f g + h < c]      (* Simpler expressions *)
Simplify[c > f  g + h j , c > f g + h j]  (* Different order     *)
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem seems due to evaluation. I think it is a bug (order should not make a difference). You can get same answer by evaluating the output from `FullSimplify` as follows.

```
a = f g + h j;
b = a;
Assuming[c > a, FullSimplify[b < c]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Assuming[c > a, Evaluate@FullSimplify[c > b]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

One also gets the same behavior using `Simplify`

[image: Mathematica graphics]

This is all using V12 on windows.